# Sieve of Eratosthenes in Z[i]

Tags: number-theory

Suppose we know all primes $p$ with $|p| \leq n$. Then the primes in the set $m$ with $n < |m| < n^2$ are the integers left in this set after removing all multiples of those known primes (Sieve of Eratosthenes). Extend this to $Z[i]$ and find all primes $\alpha$ in this domain such that $|\alpha ^2 | \leq 9$.

How do you find these primes? My approach so far: $a+bi$ has no divisors other than units and associates, and $z = (1+i)(1-i)$ is not prime. Note that $s: Z[i] \mapsto  N^{+}$ is defined by $|a+bi| = (a^2+b^2)^{1/2}$, so $a+bi$ prime implies $|a+bi|$ is prime. Then we have to consider the possibilities of prime norms (absolute values) of $7, 5, 3,$ and $2$. Any suggestions, or am I completely off with this logic?

Comment: The annulus defined by n<=norm<=n^2 seems like the natural generalisation. Then the primes it contain are those that can't be factored with a factor in 0<=norm<=n.

Comment: I wouldn't need to find specific combinations of a and b?

Comment: $|2+i|$ is not an integer but $|2+i|^2 = (2+i)(2-i)= 17$ which is why $17$ is not prime in  $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. To understand how $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is different to $\mathbb{Z}$ you should look at the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ and the Dedekind zeta function $ \zeta_{\mathbb{Z}[i]}(s) =\frac14\sum_{n+im \in \mathbb{Z}[i] \setminus \{0\}} |n+im|^{-2s} = \prod_{\mathfrak{p}} \frac{1}{1-|\mathfrak{p}|^{-2s}}  $ $= \frac{1}{1-2^{-s}}\prod_{p\equiv 1 \bmod 4} \frac{1}{(1-p^{-s})^2}\prod_{p\equiv 3 \bmod 4} \frac{1}{1-p^{-2s}}$